# How to count the mean of the Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am given Poisson process $X_t$ which has intensity $\lambda$. Is there a way to count the mean for it? I am terribly confused. I am able to count the mean of a variable which has a Poisson distribution (and that is $\lambda$), but as I understand it is not the same.

Comment: $X_t\sim \text{po}(\lambda t)$ and hence $E[X_t]=\lambda t$.

Comment: You should post this as an answer :)

Comment: Makes one wonder what kind of an introduction to Poisson processes you were exposed to, which does not comprise this.

Comment: Want a honest answer? I did not study. For several reasons, only one of them being I hate what I study :( I have this one last exam. After that (assuming I did not fail it), I would continue my job as a programmer which I enjoy. I just need to remove the stage of studies from my life and thus I needed help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A main property of a Poisson proces with parameter $\lambda$ is that $X_t\sim \text{po}(\lambda t)$ for every $t>0$. Especially we have $E[X_t]=λt$ for $t>0$.

Comment: Appreciated :))